# Node Pass Hidden Data To Other Route

Tags: node.js, express, routes, hidden

I have a route in express(`item/update/`), and after that happens I want to send them back to `/`, I also want to make `/` show an alert with 'Success' or 'Failure'. I don't want to use query string or hash because I want it to be hidden from the user. I also don't want to render `/` at `items/update` as it seems like a bad idea. Also, I have tried the javascript history api, but that seems like a hack as the history api was for something else.

Please let me know if there is any more information you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do couple of ways,

1.You can redirect to "/" url with query string. Since you don't like to add data in query string, then alternate option is session.

For example,

```
function itempUpdateHandler(request,response){
 //Do some stuff
 request.session.displayMsg = "update done successfully";
 response.setHeader("Location: http://yourdomain.com/");
 response.end();
}

function homepageHandler(request,response){
//Display message here which is read from session.
if(request.session.displayMsg){
  console.log(request.session.displayMsg);
  delete request.session.displayMsg;
}
//Do your regular suff here.
}
```

2.You have to take care somewhat more in following method, here you aren't going to redirect but you need modify you handler function as follows,

```
function itempUpdateHandler(request,response){
 //Do some stuff
 //response.setHeader("Location: http://yourdomain.com/"); //no need here
 homepageHandler(request,response, {display:true, msg: "update done successfully"});
}

function homepageHandler(request,response, moreArgs){
//Display message here which is read from session.
  if(moreArgs.display){
       console.log(moreArgs.msg);
  }
//Do your regular suff here.
}
```

Note: Assumed you are using express